# I can't get array length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have JavaScript array and fill it data from mvc modal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var letterOfResponsibilityNotes = Array(0);

    @if (Model.Step2.SelectedCountryList.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.Step2.SelectedCountryList)
        {
            <text>letterOfResponsibilityNotes["@item.Code"]='@item.LetterOfResponsibilityNote'</text>
        }
    }
```

Then I try to get `letterOfResponsibilityNotes` array length:

```
if ($(letterOfResponsibilityNotes).length > 0)
{ ... }
```

But I get always `lenth = 0`, despite I see the data in FireBug.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `@item.Code` is not a number.

```
var a = new Array(0);
a["test1"] = "test1";
a["test2"] = "test2";

// a.length is still 0 - although it has contents

a["3"] = "try a number";

// now a.length == 4, which is highest number subscript key + 1
// unfortunately that is how JS arrays work
```

To find length of your array see [Length of a javascript associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563251/length-of-a-javascript-associative-array)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
first initialize the as follow in JavaScript.

var letterOfResponsibilityNotes = new Array();

console.log(letterOfResponsibilityNotes.length);

if(letterOfResponsibilityNotes.length > 0)
{

}

if array have any value it display length of array.
```

Comment: please print your array

Answer (score 0):

delete '$' on IF.

```
if ((letterOfResponsibilityNotes).length > 0)
{ ... }
```

with $ i have this fail

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: put a 'sneak' (sorry, i don't know the name on English of this XD) on each turn of loop with `letterOfResponsibilityNotes.length` to control  if the input data on array are correct