# Array length is not correct in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array like below

```
  arr=[];
  arr[0]={"zero": "apple"};
  arr[1]={"one": "orange"};
  arr["fancy"]="what?";
```

but i am getting **length** as **2** when i do `console.log(arr.length)`  even though i am able to console all the values .
and not able to get all values while doing   console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
What is the issue here.

here is the link to fiddle [fiddle](https://repl.it/@NishamMahsin/SnowUnwittingMarkuplanguage)

Comment: you expect `arr["fancy"]="what?";` to be part of the length?

Comment: [MDN Array Length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) documentation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563251/length-of-a-javascript-associative-array

Comment: all arrays of course have a `length` property (which is what youf question is all about), so by the logic you apparently expect, `[].length` should be `1` (since it has a `length` property). Generally it's not a good idea to add string keys to an array - but if you do need to use them, then no, they don't affect the automatically-updated `length` property.

Comment: not able to get all values while doing   console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))

Comment: @NIshamMahsin - no, you wouldn't be able to, since `JSON.stringify` when applied to an array assumes you're only after the numerically-indexed properties. What actually are you trying to do? What is the use case here?

Answer (score 2):

`.length` is a special property in Javascript arrays, which is defined as "the biggest numeric index in the array plus one" (or `2^32-1`, whatever comes first). It's not "the number of elements", as the name might suggest.

When you iterate an array, either directly with `for..of` or `map`, or indirectly with e.g. `JSON.stringify`, JS just loops over all numbers from 0 to `length - 1`, and, if there's a property under this number, outputs/returns it. It doesn't look into other properties.

Comment: not able to get all values while doing   console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))

Answer (score 0):

The `length` property don't work as one will expect on arrays that are `hashtables` or `associative arrays`. This property only works as one will expect on numeric indexed arrays (and normalized, i.e, without holes). But there exists a way for get the length of an `associative array`, first you have to get the list of keys from the `associative array` using `Object.keys(arr)` and then you can use the length property over this list (that is a normalized indexed array). Like on the next example:

```js
arr=[];
arr[0]={"zero": "apple"};
arr[1]={"one": "orange"};
arr["fancy"]="what?";

console.log(Object.keys(arr).length);
```

And about this next question:

> not able to get all values while doing console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))

Your `arr` element don't have the correct format to be a **JSON**. If you want it to be a **JSON** check the syntax on the next example:

```js
jsonObj = {};
jsonObj[0] = {"zero": "apple"};
jsonObj[1] = {"one": "orange"};
jsonObj["fancy"] = "what?";

console.log(Object.keys(jsonObj).length);
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
```

Comment: not able to get all values while doing   console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))

Comment: @NIshamMahsin Updated with an answer to your commentary.

Answer (score -1):

From MDN description on arrays, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), "Arrays cannot use strings as element indexes (as in an associative array) but must use integers."

In other words, this is not Javascript array syntax
`arr["fancy"]="what?";`

Which leads to the error in `.length`.

Comment: Don't know who wrote that paragraph on MDN, but that's just silly. MDN is just a wiki, not an authoritative source, you need to double-check everything you read there.

Comment: @georg, please read the accepted answer from this related question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526860/why-does-a-string-index-in-a-javascript-array-not-increase-the-length-size). Maybe there is a confusion between associative array and array. Also reference [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp), under the section _arrays are objects_.

Comment: Yep, the same confusion over there as well. There's no dedicated "data storage" in an array, and you can perfectly assign string properties to it. In fact, all array properties are string ones, even if they look like integer numbers.

Comment: @georg ,.. and as noted [here](https://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/common-pitfalls-when-working-with-javascript-arrays/), under the section _The associative array confusion_,

`var myAssocArray = [];
myAssocArray["foo"] = "bar";`


"The above example is an abused array object. The above code works simply because arrays are objects too."

Comment: I'd suggest that instead of random internet posts you read the authoritative source, the ECMA standard, which says pretty clearly what arrays are and what they are not. Here's the link: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array-objects. Have fun!

Comment: @georg....numerous times in the ECMA documentation, "this value is an object that has a fixed length and whose **integer-indexed** properties are not sparse," seen at 22.2.3.25, 22.2.3.22, 22.2.3.21, 22.2.3.20....Now let's have the documentation define **integer-index**; "an integer index is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String (see 7.1.16) and whose numeric value is either +0 or a positive integer ≤ 253-1. _An array index is an integer index whose numeric value i is in the range +0 ≤ i < 232-1._" ...

Comment: TypedArray != Array, they are totally different things.

Comment: @georg, 22.1 **Array Objects**: Array objects are exotic objects that give special treatment to a certain class of property names. See 9.4.2 for a definition of this special treatment. ...Section 9.4.2: An Array object is an exotic object that gives special treatment to **array index** property keys (see 6.1.7)....Now to the definition of array index: " An array index is an **integer index** whose numeric value i is in the range +0 ≤ i < 232-1."...